# onClickListener is not called from the Fragment

Tags: android

In the following piece of code, even after registering an onClickLister, callback function is not getting called.

```
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view1 = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_register,
            container, false);

    final Button button = 
            (Button) view1.findViewById(R.id.button1);

    button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            updateUser(v);
        }
    });

    return view1;
}

public void updateUser(View v) {
    Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "name", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}
```

and the fragment.xml file will be, Registering an onClick Listener in the xml also doesnt help, because it calls the function in the Activity.

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context="com.example.picturejumble.Register$PlaceholderFragment" >

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/editText1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_marginLeft="34dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="37dp"
    android:ems="10"
    android:inputType="textPersonName" >

    <requestFocus />
</EditText>

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/editText2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/editText1"
    android:layout_below="@+id/editText1"
    android:layout_marginTop="54dp"
    android:ems="10"
    android:inputType="textEmailAddress" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/editText2"
    android:layout_below="@+id/editText2"
    android:layout_marginLeft="50dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="60dp"
    android:text="Button" />

 </RelativeLayout>
```

Logcat doesn't report any errors, and the code doesn't crashes as well.

The problem is that the callback is not getting called.

Comment: I have added the xml in the edit

Comment: Did you try adding `@Override` above `public void onClick(View v)` ?

Comment: Yes I tried adding that as well, doesn't help

Comment: @MukulKumarSingh please try my answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22877868/onclicklistener-is-not-called-from-the-fragment/22879617#22879617

Comment: Is the XML file name "fragment_register.xml" or "fragment.xml"?

Answer (score 1):

Just call your `updateUser(View v)` method in your xml file for button `onClick` method instead of in programming.

Use this

```
android:onClick = "updateUser"
```

for your `Button` in xml file.

Comment: This will call the callback in the Activity, not the one in the fragment

Comment: for calling the updateUser you need the right signature : void updateUser(View v)

Comment: SO what i have just specified him. That you can use like this way also.

Answer (score 0):

no need to pass the view parameter

```
button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(View v) {
        updateUser();
    }
});
public void updateUser() {
Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "name", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}
```

Comment: I need view for other functions

Answer (score 0):

use this line of code in onCreateView before inflating view `super.onCreateView(inflater, container, savedInstanceState);` if it still dosn't work please paste full code for fragment class

Answer (score 0):

Please try below code and let me know:

```
@Override
public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
    button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(View v) {
        updateUser(v);
    }
  });
}
```

Define this `Button`outside the `onCreateView` method